# Show Progress Bar in Outlook Addins

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, outlook-2007

i m developing a Outlook Add ins using  C#. hare i extract all the attachment(in doc or docx) which is attach with selected mail. i have create a button on tool bar using add in.when i click on button then all the attachment with selected mail come in to my database.now my question is that when i click on button that time some processing happens during the processing time i want to show a progress bar on my outlook window untill its finish extraction.Can any one help me to out this problem. here i include code also with extract mails attachment and sent to database

```
private void ThisApplication_NewMail()
    {
        DataTable dtImportedData = new DataTable();
        Outlook.Explorer currExplorer = this.Application.ActiveExplorer();
        Outlook.MAPIFolder folder = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder;
        Outlook.Items inBoxItems = folder.Items;
        Outlook.MailItem item = null;
        const string destinationDirectory = @"C:\TestFileSave";
        if (!Directory.Exists(destinationDirectory))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationDirectory);
        }
        dtImportedData.Columns.Add("Select", typeof(bool));
        dtImportedData.Columns.Add("Name");
        dtImportedData.Columns.Add("Experience");
        dtImportedData.Columns.Add("Company Name");
        dtImportedData.Columns.Add("Email");
        dtImportedData.Columns.Add("Mobile");
        dtImportedData.Columns.Add("Date Of Birth");
        dtImportedData.Columns.Add("Designation");
        dtImportedData.Columns.Add("Location");
        dtImportedData.Columns.Add("Qualification");
        dtImportedData.Columns.Add("Skill Set");
        dtImportedData.Columns.Add("Path");

        //DataRow dr = null;
        DataRow drExtract = null;
        try
        {
            string strFileName = string.Empty;
            Outlook.Selection selections = currExplorer.Selection;
            for (int i = 1; i <= selections.Count; ++i)
            {
                object newEmail = (object)selections[i];
                if (newEmail != null && (newEmail is Outlook.MailItem))
                {
                    item = (Outlook.MailItem)newEmail;
                    if (item.Attachments.Count > 0)
                    {
                        for (int j = 1; j <= item.Attachments.Count; j++)
                        {
                            if (item.Attachments[j].FileName.Contains(".doc") || item.Attachments[j].FileName.Contains(".docx") || item.Attachments[j].FileName.Contains(".rtf"))
                            {
                                string filePath = Path.Combine(destinationDirectory, item.Attachments[j].FileName.ToString());                                    
                                item.Attachments[j].SaveAsFile(filePath);

                                string m_Content = ClsWordManager.ReadWordFile(filePath);                                   
                                drExtract = dtImportedData.NewRow();
                                ClsResumeExtractor objExtractResume = new ClsResumeExtractor();
                                drExtract["Select"] = true;
                                drExtract["Name"] = objExtractResume.ExtractName(m_Content);
                                drExtract["Email"] = objExtractResume.ExtractEmailAddressesFromString(m_Content);
                                drExtract["Mobile"] = objExtractResume.ExtractMobile(m_Content);
                                drExtract["Qualification"] = objExtractResume.ExtractQualification(m_Content);                                  
                                drExtract["Designation"] = objExtractResume.ExtractDesignation(m_Content);
                                drExtract["Company Name"] = objExtractResume.ExtractCompanyName(m_Content);
                                drExtract["Location"] = objExtractResume.ExtractCurrentLocation(m_Content);
                                drExtract["Date Of Birth"] = objExtractResume.ExtractDateOfBirth(m_Content);
                                drExtract["Experience"] = objExtractResume.ExtractYearOfExperience(m_Content);
                                drExtract["Skill Set"] = objExtractResume.ExtractSkillSet(m_Content);
                                drExtract["Path"] = filePath;
                                dtImportedData.Rows.Add(drExtract);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Select Email which have Attchments..!");
                    }                  
                }                 
            }
            if (dtImportedData.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                SaveImportedDataOutlook objSaveImportedDataOutlook = new SaveImportedDataOutlook();
                objSaveImportedDataOutlook.grdCandidate.DataSource = dtImportedData;
                ClsCommons.OpenDialog(objSaveImportedDataOutlook);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string errorInfo = (string)ex.Message.Substring(0, 11);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Interesting SANDEEP, I see this post is kind of old. Did you ever work out your code? I'm looking to do something similar and was wondering if you would share your solution in code.